# ForEach not rendering multiple tiles

Tags: javascript

So I have a method called `get_offices()` and it outputs data properly as shown below:
[image]

Here is the function code:

```
function get_offices(page_id = 1) {
    make_request(`https://sample-api.fleishmanhillard.com/offices/?page=${page_id}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 400) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw 'There has been an error in the response status.';
            }
        }).then((json_data) => {
        const data = json_data.data.offices;
        const office = document.getElementById('office_result');
        data.forEach(entry => {
            const element = document.createElement('div');
            element.classList.add('column', 'tile', 'is-3', 'has-text-left');
            element.innerHTML = `
            <article class='tile is-child box' style="height: 300px;">
            <p class="title">` + entry.location + `</p>
            <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">ID:</span> ${entry.id}</p>
            <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Brand:</span> ${entry.brand}</p>
            <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Location:</span> ${entry.location}</p>
            <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">City:</span> ${entry.city}</p>
            </article>`;
            office.appendChild(element);
        });
    })
}
```

This works so well, but now if I want to utilize the piece of code inside the .forEach and create a function as shown below:

```
function render_office(entry) {
    const office = document.getElementById('office_result');
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    office.innerHTML = '';
    element.classList.add('column', 'tile', 'is-3', 'has-text-left');
    element.innerHTML = `
        <article class='tile is-child box' style="height: 300px;">
        <p class="title">` + entry.location + `</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">ID:</span> ${entry.id}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Brand:</span> ${entry.brand}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Location:</span> ${entry.location}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">City:</span> ${entry.city}</p>
        </article>`;
    office.appendChild(element);
}
```

Then call in the function as shown here:

```
function get_offices(page_id = 1) {
    make_request(`https://sample-api.fleishmanhillard.com/offices/?page=${page_id}`)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 400) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw 'There has been an error in the response status.';
            }
        }).then((json_data) => {
        const data = json_data.data.offices;
        const office = document.getElementById('office_result');
        office.innerHTML = '';
        data.forEach(entry => {
            render_office(entry);
        });
    })
}
```

This just outputs one single result and I don't know why it's not executing the function multiple time and looping through as shown below:
[image]

If someone could tell me why the function isn't acting the same as when the HTML code is in the block, all help will be appreciated!

Comment: Remove `office.innerHTML = '';` from the render function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a

```
office.innerHTML = '';
```

within `render_office()`, so each iteration cleans the div before adding new content.

Get rid of that line and you're good to go.

Comment: WOW, you're a legend! Didn't spot that at all, thanks so much! I will accept the answer in 12 minutes :)

Comment: Please do not answer typo-type questions. They are only useful to the asker

Comment: @mplungjan I'd rather help people than not help them.

Comment: So comment with your findings. I did not suggest you did not tell OP what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

Much faster to not update the DOM each time and you do not run the risk of such typos when you change your render

```js
const render_office(entry) {
  return `<div class="column tile is-3 has-text-left">
        <article class='tile is-child box' style="height: 300px;">
        <p class="title">${entry.location}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">ID:</span> ${entry.id}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Brand:</span> ${entry.brand}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">Location:</span> ${entry.location}</p>
        <p><span class="has-text-weight-semibold">City:</span> ${entry.city}</p>
        </article><div>`;
};
```

and use

```
 office.innerHTML = data.map(entry => render_office(entry)).join("");
```